# Is there an equivalent to `stride(from:to:by:)` that uses open intervals?

Tags: swift

The swift `stride(from:to:by)` function seems quite counter-intuitive to me.

The `to` parameter should be named `upToButNotIncluding`, since the function "Returns a sequence from a starting value to, but not including, an end value, stepping by the specified amount"

The code `print(stride(from:0, to: 10, by: 5)` should return values from 0 to 10, by 5's, right? Nope. It prints 0 and 5 but not 10.

Is there an equivalent to stride that operates on the **open** interval of the specified range? (a function that "Returns a sequence from a starting value up to **and including** an end value, stepping by the specified amount"?) That seems like what you would expect a `stride()` function to do.

Comment: `stride(from:through:by:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stride(from:through:by:)

Comment: @ielyamani Outstanding. Can you post your response as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I feel kinda dumb asking, but  `stride(from:to:by)` always bugged me.

Comment: If I didn't know, I'm sure others didn't either. I think it's worth getting an accepted answer posted (your need for attaboys notwithstanding.)

Comment: It's interesting to note that there are custom types supporting the result of both `stride(from:to:by:)` (`StrideTo` type) and `stride(from:through:by:)` (`StrideThrough` type).

Comment: In a zero-based index environment I'd glad to have an API which considers half-open ranges. Note also that the `endIndex` of an array is **not** the index of the last element.

Comment: @vadian `stride` doesn't deal with indexes though. It deals with ranges of values. In English, "count from 1 **to** 10" means "count from one up to and including 10." Thus a function `stride(from:to:by)` suggests, by it's naming, that it will give me values that range from the starting value, up to **and including** the ending value.

Comment: Just an FYI for this type of question. If you had run Xcode and then brought up the developer documentation (Shift-Cmd-0), then typed `stride(` into the search field, you would have seen your answer in the list of suggestions.

Comment: Sadly, I missed 'stride(from:through:by:)` in the auto-complete.